# Server.MapPath Access is denied On Azure

Tags: c#, excel, azure

I am exporting an excel using c# code and spreadsheetlight dll.
I am trying to insert a picture into excel, everything works well on local machine but on live web site it gives following error

```
Access to the path 'F:\sitesroot\0\Images\Logo.png' is denied
```

My c# code.

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Logo.png");
SLPicture pic = new SLPicture(filePath); //SLPicture - An inbuilt class for inserting image
```

Currently what I am doing is manually providing access rights on IIS server but which is not the correct way to go since each time I upload the service I have to redo that again and again

Any expert advice -  How I can provide access right through code?
Or How to get rid of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: you given read and write permission to Siteroot folder?

Comment: Are you using Windows Azure Virtual Machines?

Comment: @Thiago Custodio - Yes!

Comment: In reference to Thiago's question and just to be clear; Are you using Azure Cloud Services or are you using a Virtual Machine? I know you said virtual machine, but your reference to uploading sounds like you are actually using cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Cloud services...

You are supposed to use Local Storage for this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx).

Basically;

1. In your Cloud project, go to the properties for the Role and select Local Storage.
2. Add a new local storage and give it a name, i.e. "foo" and a maximum size. If this is for temporary processing rather than caching, you probably want to tick "Clean on role recycle".
3. In your code call `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("foo")` to get the folder name you can use and then do something like `Path.Combine("path","Logo.png")` to get a file name which you can then write to.