# Azure and Storage path

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure

What is the workaround for Server.MapPath() in Azure environment?
Storing and **retrieving the file path** to a certain file type stored in azure storage to probably a website that displays a image stored in azure cloud services

Comment: there are so many answers to your question, solved or lead to a solution by using SO search or google. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783173/server-mappath-access-is-denied-on-azure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server.MapPath Access is denied On Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783173/server-mappath-access-is-denied-on-azure)